# In Laravel Which middleware fires first CSRF or AUTH

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, csrf-protection

According to the **Laravel** [Website](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-protection)

Laravel will first authenticate the USER that is fire the

`Auth` middleware and then fire `CSRF` middleware.

But What if the Login page is a a fishing page and isn't it  more natural to first check if the request is from our own website and then Check if the user authentication ??.

Can some one throw some light on the same .

Thanks

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Laravel Request Lifecycle page](https://laravel.com/docs/master/lifecycle)

First the requests are passed to the middleware which are to be processed by each request defined in `app/Http/kernel.php`. **CSRF middleware** is applied at this point.

> The HTTP kernel also defines a list of HTTP middleware that all
>   requests must pass through before being handled by the application.
>   These middleware handle reading and writing the HTTP session,
>   determine if the application is in maintenance mode, verifying the
>   CSRF token, and more.

Then the request will be passed to the router. The router will impose route specific middleware then. That means, **auth** is also applied at this point.

> Once the application has been bootstrapped and all service providers
>   have been registered, the Request will be handed off to the router for
>   dispatching. The router will dispatch the request to a route or
>   controller, as well as run any route specific middleware.

Hope you got the answer.

Comment: So according to that you are also saying that , CSRF middleware will be fired first ?, On a contrary this doc  https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-protection says first authentication will happen then the CSRF token is checked ? . Am I missing something ?

Comment: " This token is used to verify that the authenticated user is the one actually making the requests to the application." This is what you mean I guess? What it says here by authenticated is not something like user login. The purpose of CSRF(Cross site request forgery) token is to avoid **unauthorized** parties from accessing your app. That is, only a component residing within your app can send valid requests to your app. Others are rejected. This is a security measure. By the way, request life cycle is the one you should refer to in order to understand what's going on.

Comment: still I don't understand what the `Authenticated user` means in that Documentation . Today an Interviewer was debating that Laravel FIrst Authenticate the User and then CSRF is checked . I think he read from  the link that I provided in my question . So what exactly is the AUthenticaTED USER MEANS THERE ?

Comment: When sending a request to an app for the first time, a session will be initialized (by attaching a laravel session cookie with the response). From the server's perspective, that client can now be identified by the cookie (seesion id) in the future requests. The CSRF token is associated with the session. For a given session, there is a random string which is used as the CSRF token. In laravel, the csrf token is available even before a user is authenticated (before logging in). Don't get mislead by a single sentence while you have a complete page describing what actually happens.

Answer (score 0):

As per the laravel docs. At first web middleware is applied after that it passess the request to other middlewares like auth and so on unless you change it.

Reference:

The VerifyCsrfToken middleware, which is included in the web middleware group, will automatically verify that the token in the request input matches the token stored in the session.

Keep in mind, the web middleware group is automatically applied to your default routes.php file by the RouteServiceProvider.

Here the web middleware

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'auth:api',
    ],
];
```